# Forcing legend entry to display markers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

Is there a way to force the patch in the legend to include a loosely spaced marker symbol in QGIS print composer?

I'm using a large, loosely spaced marker symbol to represent wetlands in a map I'm producing in QGIS.  The symbol looks good in the map, but the legend entry just shows the outline.  I would like to make the legend entry include the marker, but can't figure out how to make it happen.

How it looks on the map:
[image]

And in the legend:
[image]

I've also run into this issue with line pattern fills.
Is there a way to change either the size of the legend patch or scale the patch to be more representative?

Comment: With the legend selected, use the Item Properties panel to set the Symbol width and height... it should expand and show the fill symbol

Comment: Another workaround would be to duplicate the wetlands layer with a more closely spaced pattern fill. Turn off the duplicate layer on the map, but use it for the legend.